# Google Sign In my does not work when it's in Playstore (jetpack compose)

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, android-jetpack-compose, google-signin

When I try the app from my android studio google one-tap sign in works perfectly. but when I download the app then it won't work no matter what

there are  warnings I get from when I upload the app:

> The developer of play-services-safetynet (com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet) has reported critical issues with version 18.0.1. Consider upgrading before publishing a new release.
> Here's what the SDK developer told us:
> The SafetyNet Attestation API is being discontinued and replaced by the new Play Integrity API. Begin migration as soon as possible to avoid user disruption. The Play Integrity API includes all the integrity signals that SafetyNet Attestation offers and more, like Google Play licensing and better error messaging. Learn more and start migrating at https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/deprecation-timeline

> There is no deobfuscation file associated with this App Bundle. If you use obfuscated code (R8/proguard), uploading a deobfuscation file will make crashes and ANRs easier to analyse and debug. Using R8/proguard can help reduce app size. Learn more

Comment: Are you using pro guard?

Comment: I have this text so I dont think so. (There is no deobfuscation file associated with this App Bundle. If you use obfuscated code (R8/proguard), uploading a deobfuscation file will make crashes and ANRs easier to analyse and debug. Using R8/proguard can help reduce app size.)

Comment: I also upload the App as a signed bundle @SemicolonSpace

Comment: I don't see why it doesn't work when installing it from Play Store, but [here](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) is a working solution with the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).

Comment: @SemicolonSpace i found that in gradle app it uses pro guard. `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you need to configure you project in Google API Console.
You have to add package and SHA1 signature of you release build.

Check this https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#configure_a_project

or https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-started#api-console

Here the instruction how to get SHA1 https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

Comment: i've been trying to get SHA1 release one. had hard time finding it since I also found out there is debug and release. when I check in android studio I found SHA-1 to be null for release. and just now I made the SHA-1 for release same as the debug one. will test it out

Comment: You should not use debug SHA1 signature for release build. Try to find a way to get release SHA1.

Comment: ok thank you so much I added SHA-1 of the google console to firebase.